Is the product of primes from $n/2$ to $n$ always less than $2^n$?

Calculating for the first few $n$ and assuming that $p_{i}$ is the $i$th prime, it appears that $\left( \prod_{(\frac{n}{2} \lt p_{i} \le n)} p_{i} \right) \lt 2^{n}$ .
For example, $\left( \prod_{(\frac{31}{2} \lt p_{i} \le 31)} p_{i} \right) = 17 \times 19 \times 23 \times 29 \times 31 = 6678671 \lt 2^{31} = 2147483648$ .
If this is not true, which value of $n$ provides a counterexample?  If true, how might it be proven?


Using Mathematica to compute these values for larger cases of $n$, it appears that the growth is asymptotically of the form $a^n$ but with $1<a<2$. My guess based on the numerics is that the growth is $e^{n/2}$. For instance, for $n=2000$ I get a value $\approx e^{990.499}\approx 2^{1429}\ll 2^{2000}$.

We have $p_n\cdots p_{2n}>2^n$ for $n>10544111 $, see this post. Perhaps this can be used for your product.

Using @DietrichBurde's link as a reference, the problem amounts to showing $\theta(2n)-\theta(n) < (2\ln 2)n$ where $\theta$ is the first Chebyshev function. The known asymptotic growth is $\theta(n)\sim n$, hence $\theta(2n)-\theta(n)\sim n/2$ as I guessed above. The linked post shows $\theta(2n)-\theta(n)>n(\ln 2)$.

Let $P_n:=\prod_{p\leq n}p$ denote the product of all primes no greater than $n$. Then
$$\log P_n=\sum_{p\leq n}\log p=:\theta(n),$$
where $\theta$ denotes the Chebyshev function. Then your product can be expressed as
$$\prod_{n/2<p\leq n}p=\frac{P_n}{P_{n/2}}=\frac{\exp(\theta(n))}{\exp(\theta(n/2))}=\exp(\theta(n)-\theta(n/2)),$$
so you want to show that
$$\theta(n)-\theta(n/2)<n\ln2.$$
The linked Wikipedia page also includes some bounds for $\theta$, such as
\begin{eqnarray}
\theta(n)\leq n+0.006788\frac{n}{\ln n}\\
\theta(n)\geq n-0.006788\frac{n}{\ln n},
\end{eqnarray}
for all $n\geq n_0$, where $n_0:=p_{698306}=10544111$ is the $698306$th prime. It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\theta(n)-\theta(n/2)
&\leq&\left(n+0.006788\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)-\left(n/2-0.006788\frac{n/2}{\ln(n/2)}\right)\\
&=&n\left(\frac12+0.006788\left(\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac12\frac{1}{(\ln n-\ln2)}\right)\right),
\end{eqnarray}
and of course the parenthesised part is decreasing for sufficiently large $n$, which suggests that your inequality does indeed hold. A bit of elementary calculus shows that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac12\frac{1}{(\ln x-\ln2)}\right)=-\frac1x\left(\frac{1}{(\ln x)^2}-\frac12\frac{1}{(\ln x-\ln2)^2}\right),$$
which indeed shows that $\theta(n)-\theta(n/2)$ is decreasing whenever
$$2(\ln n-\ln2)^2>(\ln n)^2,$$
or equivalently $n>2^{2+\sqrt{2}}$. This shows that for $n\geq n_0$ we have
$$\theta(n)-\theta(n/2)<n\left(\frac12+0.006788\left(\frac{1}{\ln n_0}-\frac12\frac{1}{(\ln n_0-\ln2)}\right)\right)<0.5002005n,$$
and hence that for $n\geq n_0$ you have
$$\prod_{n/2<p\leq n}p<1.6491^n,$$
where $1.6491\approx\exp(0.5002005)$.
